# Pygame troubleshooting black screen: Alien Invasion

Tags: python, pygame, display

I have been following the Python Crash Course Project to create a space invaders game. I have been able to code to the point where the game window will open but instead of getting the background with my image in the middle bottom of the screen I am met with a black screen. I am new to coding and have seen this has been a similar issue for others as well. I am using Python 3.8 have successfully uploaded the correct pip install (https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/updates/python3_8/#pygame-on-python-38) as well.

Here is the code for Alien Invasion:

```
import sys

import pygame

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall Class to manage game assests and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1100, 700))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game"""
        while True:
            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            # Make the most recently drawn screen Visible
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()

def __init__(self):
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    # Set the Background Color
    self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)

def run_game(self):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()

    #redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
    self.screen.fill(self.bg_color)

    #make the most recently drawn screen visible.
    pygame.display.flip()

import pygame

from settings import Settings

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall Class to manage game assets and behavior"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()
        self.settings = Settings()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (self.settings.screen_width, self.settings.screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

    def run_game(self):
        # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)

        #make most recently drawn screen visible.
        pygame.display.flip()

from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall class to manage game assets and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop.
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()

        # Make most recently drawn screen visible
        pygame.display.flip()
    
    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game."""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            # Redraw the screen during each pass through the loop
            break

    def _check_events(self):
        """Respond to keypress and mouse events."""
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                sys.exit()

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game"""
        while True:
            self._check_events()
            self._update_screen()

    def _check_events(self):
        --snip--

    def _update_sceen(self):
        """Update images on the screen, and flip to the new screen."""
        self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)
        self.ship.blitme()

        pygame.display.flip()
```

Settings

```
 class Settings:
    """A class to store all settings for Alien Invasion."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game's static settings."""
        # Screen settings.
        self.screen_width = 1100
        self.screen_height = 700
        self.bg_color = (230, 230, 230)
```

Spaceship:

```
  import pygame

class Ship:
    """A class to manage the ship."""

    def __init__(self, ai_game):
        """Initialize the ship and set its starting position."""
        self.screen = ai_game.screen
        self.screen_rect = ai_game.screen.get_rect()

        # Load the ship image and get its rect.
        self.image = pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # Start each new ship at the bottom center of the screen
        self.rect.midbottom = self.screen_rect.midbottom

    def blitme(self):
        """Draw the ship at current location"""
        self.screen.blit(self.image, self.rect)
```

I am currently using the Python Crash Course book by Eric Matthes.

Comment: Can you share some information on your environment? What OS, packages and their versions, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have a basic misunderstanding. It seems that you have tried to distribute the drawing to multiple implementations of a class named `AlienInvasion`. Read about [Class](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html): *"Classes provide a means of bundling data and functionality together."*. A class is a type you have to put the implementation in one "class". Actually each of the `AlienInvasion` classes in your implementation is a different type in a different module. It is not possible to distribute the implementation of a class and methods of a class to different modules.

Create instances of `Settings` and `Ship` in the class `AlienInvasion`:

```py
self.settings = Settings()
self.ship = Ship(self)
```

The instance method `run_game` of the class `AlienInvasion` implements the main application loop. The main application loop has to:

- handle the events by either [`pygame.event.pump()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.pump) or [`pygame.event.get()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html#pygame.event.get).
- update the game states and positions of objects dependent on the input events and time (respectively frames)
- clear the entire display or draw the background
- draw the entire scene (`blit` all the objects)
- update the display by either [`pygame.display.update()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.update) or [`pygame.display.flip()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.flip)

e.g.:

```py
import pygame
from settings import Settings
from ship import Ship

class AlienInvasion:
    """Overall Class to manage game assests and behavior."""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initialize the game, and create game resources."""
        pygame.init()

        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1100, 700))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")

        self.settings = Settings()
        self.ship = Ship(self)

    def run_game(self):
        """Start the main loop for the game"""
        while True:
            # Watch for keyboard and mouse events.
            for event in pygame.event.get():
                if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                    sys.exit()

            # clear display
            self.screen.fill(self.settings.bg_color)  

            # draw scene
            self.ship.blitme()      

            # Make the most recently drawn screen Visible
            pygame.display.flip()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Make a game instance, and run the game.
    ai = AlienInvasion()
    ai.run_game()
```